# Calculating an average from survey input in a django template

Tags: django, django-templates, python-2.7, django-views

I'm trying to display survey results on a django template page.  I wan't to be able to show the average based on specific demographics and the rating given to each category.  I already save the survey response data as in integer in the survey form view that I have.  This is what I have so far for the rest:

```
#views.py
def statistics(request):
    male = Survey.objects.filter(gender='male')
    ...
    #Other demographics filtered
    ...

    def avgcalc(myDemographic, myCategory):
        ratings = []

        for x in myDemographic:
            ratings.append(myCategory)

        intTotal = 0
        intCount = 0
        intLenMyList = len(myDemographic)

        while(intCount <  intLenMyList):
            intTotal += ratings[intCount]
            intCount += 1

        return intTotal/intLenMyList
...
#rest of view rendering template, etc.
```

Now is where I run into the problem.  How can I easily display the data for each category based on the demographic? For instance, in my template I would like to do

```
#template.html
Demographic: Male
Total responses for this demographic: {{ male|length }}
Average response for specific category: {{ avgcalc(male, category) }}
```

{{ male|length }} works fine to display the number of male respondents, However, in the templates, I cannot use {{ avgcalc(male, category) }}.  In reality, I have a table set up already, and there are about 20 demographics with a dozen category ratings, so if possible, I would like to avoid having to put each one in my view (i.e. male_category_calc = avgcalc(male, category) for each demographic and category.  Is this even possible, or do I need to do it the extremely long way?  I am okay with having to type each one into my template, as long as it works.  Thanks for any help or advice.

Comment: Is `avgcalc` called based on some kind of data selection on the client or is the entire page rendered with the data?

Comment: The entire page would be rendered with the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend template functionality with [custom template tag or filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/). Like this one:

**foo_app/templatetags/foo_tags.py:**

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def avgcalc(myDemographic, myCategory):
    ratings = []

    for x in myDemographic:
        ratings.append(myCategory)

    intTotal = 0
    intCount = 0
    intLenMyList = len(myDemographic)

    while(intCount <  intLenMyList):
        intTotal += ratings[intCount]
        intCount += 1

    return intTotal/intLenMyList
```

Then in your **template.html**:

```
{% load foo_tags %}

{{ male|avgcalc:category }}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am unable to see if it actually works for me yet because apparently this wasn't the only confusion I had with what I am trying to do. I can't seem to get my brain to work right now. So within my Survey model that contains the demographic fields to be displayed on the form, I also have the different categories to be rated. I was thinking that using male.categoryA would work for specifying the category for myCategory, but it doesn't, so when I try to use {{ male|avgcalc:male.categoryA }} it is unsuccessful. What would I need in order to get all the answers from males for categoryA?

Answer (score 0):

You can django's custom template tag to do that.

For computing average values you may want to check out django's [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/)

They have the Avg function to compute average values of a specific field. (in your case the category)

```
from django.db.models import Avg
Model.objects.all().aggregate(Avg('attribute'))
```

Comment: This would somewhat work, however there are a couple of issues with it.  First, the webpage displays {'categoryA__avg': 5.5} instead of just 5.5 and second, I would have to type each out in the view (for example Model.objects.filter(gender="male").aggregate(Avg('categoryA')). Is there a way to overcome both of those issues?

Comment: Make a function out of it with category as the argument. Like `def calc_avg(category)` . It's a dict, so get the value by adding `['attribute_name__avg']` to the end.